# Convert sfc-column into two columns with their corresponding x and y coordinates

Tags: r, vector, sf

I have a `sfc`-column with just 6 points. I'd like to make these point to markers in a leaflet-map in `R`. So I thought that it would be a nice idea to convert them into two columns: `x` and `y`. The `sfc`-column looks like the following. Probably an easy task, but I have no idea how to split up the values from each point into two columns.

```
Geometry set for 6 features 
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 9.952508 ymin: 53.57191 xmax: 10.02894 ymax: 53.62756
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
POINT (9.988762 53.5924)
POINT (9.975138 53.57954)
POINT (9.952508 53.57584)
POINT (10.02894 53.57191)
POINT (10.00046 53.59458)
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: `st_coordinates`.

Starting with a data frame:

```
> pts = data.frame(1:10,1:10)
```

and making a spatial points data frame like yours:

```
> spts = st_as_sf(data.frame(pts),coords=1:2)
> spts
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
        geometry
1    POINT (1 1)
2    POINT (2 2)
3    POINT (3 3)
4    POINT (4 4)
5    POINT (5 5)
6    POINT (6 6)
7    POINT (7 7)
8    POINT (8 8)
9    POINT (9 9)
10 POINT (10 10)
```

you can get the coordinates:

```
> st_coordinates(spts)
    X  Y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

as a two-column matrix:

```
> class(st_coordinates(spts))
[1] "matrix"
```